# ClassList.add() is not working for every each item on click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the forEach method for adding class to more than one same element on click using querySelectorAll. However, my problem is when I click on each item my code works like that;

ITEMS:

- Worked - [class added] ("I clicked")
- Not Worked - [class not added] ("I clicked")
- Worked - [class added] ("I clicked")
- Not Worked - [class not added] ("I clicked")

Here is my code:

**JavaScript:**

```
const options = document.querySelectorAll("#options")
    options.forEach(opt => {
        opt.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            let settings = e.target.parentElement.nextSibling.nextSibling
            settings.classList.toggle("is-settings-visible");
    
        })
    })
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="blog-post-buttons">
    <button id="twitter-post-modal" class="twitter-post">Post To Twiter</button>
    <button id="linkedln-post-modal" class="linkedln-post">Post To Linkedln</button>
    <i id="options" class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
</div>
<div class="options-post">
    <ul>
        <li id="web-sharing">Web Sharing options</li>
        <li id="sign-in-accounts">Sign in social accounts</li>
        <li id="help-tutorials">Help and tutorials</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.options-post{
    visibility: hidden;
 }

.options-post.is-settings-visible{
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

Anyone can help me, please?
https://jsfiddle.net/cbxeyosf/23/

Comment: Can you explain more your problem? your code works. But I couldn't get what you want to do.

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/t5qmh0uy/ The class `is-settings-visisble` is toggled on `div.options-post` for each click on the horizontal ellipsis icon.

Comment: There is more than one save div that I shared. When I try to click on each div, the class that I am trying to implement only works for 1 empty one full. It works for the first element, not for the second, and work for the third element

Comment: I tried with multiple `div`s as well and it still works. Try using a single `nextElementSibling` instead of two `nextSibling`

Comment: I send these divs to UI dynamically with a function. I think the problem is in my function. Because they also work for me when I copy and paste to HTML.

Comment: My problem is here actually. https://jsfiddle.net/cbxeyosf/23/ If you check this link out you will notice that when you press on ""ADD" button and try to click on  dots button it will not work for every click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js

```
let btn = document.querySelector(".add");
  const screen = document.querySelector(".screen");

  var count = 0;
  btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{

   let html = `
      <div class="blog-post-buttons">
      <button id="twitter-post-modal" class="twitter-post">Post To 
        Twiter</button>
      <button id="linkedln-post-modal" class="linkedln-post">Post To 
        Linkedln</button>
      <i id="options${count}" class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="options-post">
      <ul>
         <li id="web-sharing">Web Sharing options</li>
         <li id="sign-in-accounts">Sign in social accounts</li>
         <li id="help-tutorials">Help and tutorials</li>
      </ul>
      </div>`;

      let messageDiv = document.createElement("div");
      messageDiv.classList.add("message");
      messageDiv.innerHTML = html;
      screen.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", messageDiv);

      const iconElem = document.getElementById("options"+count);


      iconElem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          console.log("t");
          let settings = e.target.parentElement.nextSibling.nextSibling
          settings.classList.toggle("is-settings-visible");
      })
    count++;
})
```

maybe you can use this way

Comment: Hi Kaan, thanks for your answer.My problem is here https://jsfiddle.net/cbxeyosf/23/

Comment: okay i edit my solution. the problem was that you clicked add button it adds 'listener' to opt elemet many times. because of that the opt elements that has even numbers does not work.

Comment: I appreciate your help!